# access post parameters in handler

Tags: go, mux

I can access `GET` parameters using [mux](http://github.com/gorilla/mux):

```
import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
func main(){
     rtr := mux.NewRouter()
     rtr.HandleFunc("/logon", logonGet).Methods("GET")
}
func logonGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    login := params["login"]
}
```

But cannot figure out how to access `POST` params

```
func main(){
     rtr := mux.NewRouter()
     rtr.HandleFunc("/logon", logonPost).Methods("POST")
}
func logonPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // how to get POST parameters from request
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

By using [`(*http.Request).FormValue`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) method.

```
func logonPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    login := r.FormValue("login")
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Does this refer to the JSON body or where exactly is the `login` field that's being retrieved? I'm trying this method but `FormValue` always just returns an empty string.

Comment: @nburk No, this is about a usual HTML form. For JSON you need to decode a structure from a body.